# Monitoring node processes within docker containers

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that creates 3 Node-js containers and an Nginx container as a forward proxy to load balance.

**How can I monitor and restart the Node-js containers when and if they fail?**

Traditional wisdom states all containers should only have a single proccess. So running systemd (or similar) on the node containers would break that pattern.

**__--== UPDATE ==--__**

As @mishunika stated below, if the node process fails with a correct exit code and there are correct restart policies on the container, it will restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it really depends in what circumstances a node.js container may fail, and if it does so, the container should probably stop and return an exit status code.

As of docker 1.2, there are so-called [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart). I suppose that a failing node instance may stop the container and return a non-zero. In that case you can specify the **on-failure** policy at the container level.

In compose you can specify it by:

```
container_name:
    build: .
    ...
    restart: on-failure
```

Comment: When you "failing node instance may stop the container" is that 100% as i can't find anything in the docs surrounding that.

Comment: If the process in the container exits, the container stops, and the exit status of the process is available in the container inspect. A container doesn't exist without a process.  Not sure where that's documented, it's just one of those things that is fundamental to how docker works.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan yes, as dnephin said, if the process exits, the container stops. This is a fundamental thing.

Anyway, as I said before it depends what you mean by "failing". For example, if the node.js enters a unresponsive state and it doesn't exit then the above procedure won't work. Also, neither supervisor nor systemd would detect that, but I don't think it is the case for such a popular product as nodejs.